# (Kotlin) Loading file from internal storage and using it to draw on a canvas

Tags: canvas, kotlin, getfiles

I'm having problems using a text file saved in my app's Internal Storage and using it to determine what bitmaps will be drawn on a canvas and what'll be their placement. The file is being succesfully created by my app. It seems like there's a problem with "filesDir" but only under certain circumstances.

The problem is, when I'm inserting

```
val file: List<String> = File(this.filesDir, "TempLayoutData.txt").readLines()
```

inside "class Canvass" or "override fun onDraw", "filesDir" suddenly becomes an "unresolved reference".

So - in order to bypass this - I've created class "Layout". It looks like this:

```
class Layout : AppCompatActivity(){
    val file: List<String> = File(this.filesDir, "TempLayoutData.txt").readLines()
    val stagewidth = file[0].toInt() * 10
    val stagelength = file[1].toInt() * 10

    var layout = Array(stagelength) { IntArray(stagewidth) }

    var rowcounter = 0
    var columncounter = 0

    var read = File(this.filesDir, "TempLayout.txt").forEachLine {
        for (i in it) {
            layout[rowcounter][columncounter] = (i - 48).toInt()
            columncounter++
        }
        rowcounter++
        columncounter = 0
    }
}
```

I've tested it inside "override fun onCreate" of my ViewLayout class (which also containts class Canvas) and it worked like a charm.

When it's right inside class Canvas brought to life using

```
val layout = Layout()
```

it builds without errors, however when I'm running my app on my phone, the following error occurs: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference"

As the source of the error, it points directly at

```
val file: List<String> = File(this.filesDir, "TempLayoutData.txt").readLines()
```

inside my Layout class, when its' instance is being created inside Canvas class.

And I just don't know what to do. I've done some search on Google and there's literally nothing about people trying to use file inside app's Internal Storage to base their drawing on it.

Comment: Problem is You should never manually instantiate `Activity` classes - they are critical part of android framework and will misbehave if they are not started with an intent.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, if I erase "AppCompatActivity()", "filesDir" becomes an unresolved reference, so my Layout class must be an activity, right? If I'm going to start it with an intent however, how exactly can I do it? What's most important for me, is to create a value which is Layout class' instance (that's why I'm using "val layout = Layout()"). How I'm supposed to go about it using intent?

Comment: [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) is a method of `Context` so You don't have to extend activity. Just add a `context` field into your `Layout` class (initialized in constructor) and use it to get `context.filesDir` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pawel! It works like a charm! I've also needed to change "val layout = Layout()" to "val layout = Layout(context)" and now it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for taking care of it so late, but I'm officially answering this question. All thanks to Pawel's help!

First of all, my **Layout** class should never be an activity class. I've removed the extension and added constructor with **Context**. I've also changed "**this.**" to "**context.**" before "**filesDir**". It now looks like this:

```
class Layout (context: Context){
    private val file: List<String> = File(context.filesDir, "TempLayoutData.txt").readLines()
    val stageWidth = file[0].toInt() * 10
    val stageLength = file[1].toInt() * 10

    var layout = Array(stageLength) { IntArray(stageWidth) }

    private var rowCounter = 0
    private var columnCounter = 0

    var read = File(context.filesDir, "TempLayoutLayout.txt").forEachLine {
        for (i in it) {
            layout[rowCounter][columnCounter] = (i - 48).toInt()
            columnCounter++
        }
        rowCounter++
        columnCounter = 0
    }
}
```